# Mesh not UV unwrapping well?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

I have my model made and seams marked but the mesh doesn't unpack well. I tried exporting and painting it in Photoshop anyway but doesn't apply like it should. What am I doing wrong?

Solid view:

[image: Solid View]

Textured View:

[image: Textured View]

Rendered View:

[image: Rendered View]

Seams/Wireframe View:

[image: Seams/Wireframe View]

Comment: It looks like your normals are messed up. Try selecting the entire mesh in edit mode and pressing `Ctrl N`.

Comment: Thanks, everything looks like it should. Any clue why I would be missing vertices after import into Unity?

Comment: Did that fixed it (I wasn't sure what you meant in your comment)? As for exporting to unity, that sounds like a separate question (and should be asked as such) :)

Comment: all issues fixed

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the normals are not consistent.

Those dark spots on the mesh are caused by flipped normals. By enabling face normals display in *3D view > Properties region > Mesh display > Normals*, you will notice that they are pointing the wrong direction:

[image]

To fix this, select everything in edit mode (<kbd>A</kbd>) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.

Now all the normals should be facing outwards:

[image]

Comment: I flipped the Normals but it's still odd. Here is what it looks like.
[link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byz8DRhnzr0RR2tPaGJjRHJBYzg/edit?usp=sharing[link]

Comment: @Jonny314 ??? I'm confused.. What does that have to do with this?

Comment: @ Gandalf3: Jonny314 just seems to be unfamiliar with this sites format.

Comment: @Jonny314: Normally around here it's customary to start a new question for each distinct category of issue.  It would make searching this site very difficult if random topics were all mixed together on every thread.  People would have to dig through piles of unrelated info just to find what they are looking for.  Feel free to bring up the new problem as a separate question.  This way things here will stay more focused and organized.